# SUB TOTAL in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I to try to get subtotal of these numbers through  formula but sub total is wrong please check this image
check image

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs6AC.png)

i use this formula here locamount is feild name and @test is parameter..

```
if isnull ({@test})
then {dt1.locamount}
else
{@test}
```

@test parameter

```
if {dt.acdocno}+{dt.fiscalyear} = {esy.InvRef1}
then
{esy.Invpmt1}
else if 
{dt.acdocno}+{dt.fiscalyear} = {esy.InvRef2}
then
{esy.Invpmt2}
else if 
{dt.acdocno}+{dt.fiscalyear} = {esy.InvRef3}
then
{esy.Invpmt3}
else if 
{dt.acdocno}+{dt.fiscalyear} = {esy.InvRef4}
then
{esy.Invpmt4} ......
```

above code continue till 50 number comes

i click on insert fields and select formula field then i write formula and save this as SUB_TOTAL then  drag this field i.e. subtotal on report

how to solve this

Comment: Where did you place the formula

Comment: in report.. and i group this by vendor no.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something obvious, but... you should be able to accomplish this by using **grouping** and **summaries** or **running totals**

1. In your report, go to Report > Group Expert. Select the field you want a subtotal on (VendorNo)
2. Create a running total for the field you want to summarize - If you want to summarize a computed field, then first create a formula for the computed field (say, {dt.acdocno}+{dt.fiscalyear}), then use that formula as your field to summarize in the running total.

[image]

The results should look like this

[image]

If this isn't what you need, could you provide some detail about the report design and tables used?